# Is it possible to use XML to provide content (like images) to a WPF Application?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

If I had a WPF application that has a bunch of static images, text, and other things of the sort. Would there be a way to change this content through XML rather than having to change it through the XAML every-time?

For example, is this possible:

```
<Image Source="{ xml written path to image }" />
```

? If so, how.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749287(v=vs.110).aspx) helps.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the image can't be XML, but you can read the XML in your code and provide a uri to the Image.Source. All in runtime without changing any XAML.

Comment: So the XML can have the path? And the Image source reads from that specific location?

Comment: Yes, the XML can contain whatever you want. For exmaple a path, and you just need to read that path and sync it with the Image.Source.